# draw only one object by button and undo button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, calayer, cashapelayer

i am beginner in swift, and now i am a little fighting with maybe simple thing.

if i click on button undo, the MyDrawView should be clear, and if i click on polygon a fill for example purple, and then i click on circle, to have only one object.

something like this:

[image: only 1 object]

but now i have this:

[image: but now i have this]

my code:

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore

class MyDrawView: UIView{

    var circle = UIBezierPath()
    let polygon = UIBezierPath()

    let shapeLayer1 = CAShapeLayer()
    let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()


    func drawCircle(){
        circle = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 200, y: 300), radius: CGFloat(100), startAngle: CGFloat(0), endAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi * 2), clockwise: true)

        shapeLayer1.path = circle.cgPath

        shapeLayer1.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer1.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor 
        shapeLayer1.lineWidth = 3.0 

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer1)
    }


    func drawPolygon(){
        polygon.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
        polygon.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 230, y: 90))
        polygon.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 240, y: 250))
        polygon.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 280))
        polygon.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 100, y: 150))
        polygon.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))

        shapeLayer4.path = polygon.cgPath

        shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor 
        shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor 
        shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 3.0 

         layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
    }


    @IBAction func clickButtonUndo(_ sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBAction func clickButtonCircle(_ sender: UIButton) {
        drawCircle()
    }

    @IBAction func clickButtonPolygon(_ sender: UIButton) {
        drawPolygon()
    }




    @IBAction func buttonPurple(_ sender: UIButton) {
        shapeLayer1.path = circle.cgPath
        shapeLayer2.path = polygon.cgPath

        shapeLayer1.fillColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        shapeLayer1.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor 
        shapeLayer1.lineWidth = 3.0 

        shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor 
        shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 3.0 

        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer1)
        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make an algorithm with true/false
for example:

```
var circleBool = true
```

var polygonBool = true

```
@IBAction func clickButtonCircle(_ sender: UIButton) {
  if circleBool == true {
    drawCircle()
  polygonBool = false
```

}
    }

```
@IBAction func clickButtonPolygon(_ sender: UIButton) {
   if polygonBool == true {
    drawPolygon()
   circleBool = false

}

@IBAction func clickButtonUndo(_ sender: UIButton) {
circleBool = true
polygonBool = true

}
```

(for undo button idk how to clear but try to draw x:0 and y:0)

Answer (score 1):

You are adding two layers on your own

```
layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer1)
layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
```

if you want to have just one shape .... use just one shapeLayer ... Assign it shape on each button tap ... and call `setNeedsLayout()` .. don't use multiple shapeLayers for multiple shape

you can have an Enum

```
public enum ShapeType {
         case circle
         case square
         case star
         case Polygon
     }
```

Then in your View class

```
public var shape: ShapeType {
        get {
            return _shape
        }
        set(newValue) {
            _shape = newValue
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
```

you can have default shape

```
    private let ilayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private var _shape: ShapeType = .circle
```

Then you can write a function

```
// MARK: - Base shape BezierPath

private func getBaseShape(frame:CGRect) -> UIBezierPath? {

    switch _shape {
    case .circle:
        return UIBezierPath(ovalIn: group)
    case .square:
        return  UIBezierPath(roundedRect: group, cornerRadius: 8)
    case .star:
        return drawStarShape()
    case .polygon:
        return drawpolygonPath()

    }
}
```

and assign that to shape

```
let getShapePath = getBaseShape(group: group)
```